# Visual Studio Code - multiple keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there any way to set two keyboard shortcuts for one action in VS code? For example, I want to move the cursor to the left by pressing left arrow key or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.

Is it possible to add multiple keybindings to a shortcut?

Comment: As far as I know, you need to make a custom macro for both to get that to work.

Comment: I have edited your question for the sole purpose of making it more likely to show up in search engines. This is exactly what I was looking for and the below answer is also exactly what I was looking for. But it took me a while of searching for different phrases and scrolling to find this.

Answer (score 106):

> Edit: Starting from **1.52** it's possible from keybindings GUI:

[image: keybindings gui context menu add keybinding]

---

What stops you from editing `keybindings.json`?

```json
{
    "key": "left",
    "command": "cursorLeft",
    "when": "textInputFocus"
},
{
    "key": "alt+a",
    "command": "cursorLeft"
}
```

It can be opened from Command Palette `Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)`

Or by clicking the file icon from keybindings GUI page:

[image]

Comment: It works. To access keybindings.json one can access the settings and click on the link

Comment: it would be _kinda_ helpful if your answer actually mentioned _how_ you add multiple keybindings. The answer is: create multiple entries, one per desired key. But that's not obvious; it could just as easily have been one entry with a delimited list for key.

Answer (score 10):

Updating the previous answer and adding tiny more details, atleast in the current 2020 version it seems like after changing the keybindings (atleasy cursor up & down), VSCode creates an entry in the JSON file that can be accessed from Alex's answer. The JSON will contain the new entry you made but also the changed entry with a '-' negative sign on the key instruction. Just remove the '-' negative sign and both your keybindings should work like a charm! Obviously don't forget to save!

Comment: In version 1.53.2 there is no such json file, nor does the Keyboard Shortcuts GUI have any link above the 'Type to search in keybindings' text entry :(

Comment: That's weird... Don't you see any 'keyboard shortcut JSON' option in the menu tabs? I switched to sublime now so cannot check myself.

Comment: +1 for being able to escape from VSCode.. i recently took intellij for a spin and realised how large the chasm is between VSCode and real developer tools..