# multiple key bindings in vscode (visual studio code) cursor right disabled after creation on new keybinding

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-keybinding

Am new in VScode and i added a new shortcut to move the cursor right, as the right arrow key, forces me to move my hand, NOW THE RIGHT ARROW IS DISABLED and i can do other tasks such moving a full word right as the shortcut has completely replaced the right arrow key,

1. can someone tell me an easy shortcut to move the cursor to the right without the right arrow after each line of code, such as print(" hello world")*cursor here*
2. or tell me how to make both my custom shortcut sequence and the right arrow key work
   also i noticed that the default keybinding (shift+alt+i) to move the cursor to the end of the line  never worked.
   thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a similar post here: [Visual Studio Code - multiple keyboard shortcuts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45383882/visual-studio-code-multiple-keyboard-shortcuts)
and I've fixed moving right, but i can't do the same with the arrow up, no matter what keybinding i set,also would be nice to be able to add such *moving shortcuts* without having to affect the current right setting
**here is my current code on the keybiding.jsonfile - could anyone suggest a fix on this code without disrupting the current settings? **

```
{
    "key": "shift+alt+i",
    "command": "-editor.action.insertCursorAtEndOfEachLineSelected",
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
},

{
    "key": "shift+alt+r",
    "command": "cursorRight",
    "when": "textInputFocus"
},

{`enter code here`
    "key": "Right",
    "command": "cursorRight"
}

{
    "key": "Left",
    "command": "cursorLeft"
}

{
    "key": "right",
    "command": "-cursorRight",
    "when": "textInputFocus"
},
{
    "key": "shift+alt+l",
    "command": "cursorLeft",
    "when": "textInputFocus"
},
{
    "key": "left",
    "command": "-cursorLeft",
    "when": "textInputFocus"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've deleted all the commands and replaced them with this all seems to work enter code here

```json
{
        "key": "alt+r",
        "command": "cursorRight",
        "when": "textInputFocus"
    },
    {
        "key": "Right",
        "command": "cursorRight"
    },
    // down
    {
        "key": "alt+d",
        "command": "cursorDown"
    },
    // UP
    {
        "key": "alt+u",
        "command": "cursorUp"
    },
    // LEFT
    {
        "key": "alt+l",
        "command": "cursorLeft",
    },
    {
        "key": "Left",
        "command": "cursorLeft"
    },
```